# Travis not testing new commits after GitHub repository renamed

Tags: git, github, travis-ci

It took me 3 days to notice that Travis-CI isn't testing the commits I push after I changed my repository's name. I tried every option that I was able to find here, on GitHub and on Travis help page. Already revoked my account hook and the repository webhook and created new ones. None of this worked. The repository is: https://github.com/akz92/estudeantes
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the "Build pushes" option was unchecked. After turning it back on everything is working fine.
To turn "Build pushes" on just go to your project's travis-ci page, then go to settings and you should see the option on the right side.